# Facebook, how to share a link thats just an image,

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

This Facebook post https://www.facebook.com/damnlolcom/posts/812448255487528 looks like a photo post but is actually link, it clicks through to an external site.

I have tried sharing a link, removing all og metatags from my site except image path but it doesn't look like that.

The closest I can get is the default link behaviour without any title description, so just an image with the url besides/below rather than displayed over the top of the bottom of the image.

So what sort of post is this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does your thing look like?

Comment: That _is_ just a normal link post. Facebook might just decide not to show title and description in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the url in [linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.damnlol.com%2Fturns-out-my-friends-mom-is-a-racist-47206.html) .

**raw tags found on page**

```
Meta Tag    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="172220699476208" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Damn! LOL" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="Turns Out My Friend&#039;s Mom Is A Racist" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:description" content="Click for your daily dose..." />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.damnlol.com/turns-out-my-friends-mom-is-a-racist-47206.html" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.damnlol.com/pics/998/d6c09d2cc01d04bc5e47483e85774aee.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

Everything looks normal here . They are not using anything special . It is just facebook presents links in slightly different designs on feed on different times .

ps : try setting `property="og:type" content="article"`